# Cross Validation on R Ranger Library

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, r-ranger

Hello I have the following ranger model:

```
X <- train_df[, -1]
y <- train_df$Price

rf_model <- ranger(Price ~ ., data = train_df, mtry = 11 ,splitrule = "extratrees" ,min.node.size = 1, num.trees =100)
```

I am trying to accomplish two things,

1. Give me an average performance metric, cross-validating across non intersecting variance data sets, and give me a more stable accuracy metric, despite the change in seed value
2. Set up cross validation to find the most optimal mtry, and num.trees combo.

What I have tried:

**The following worked for optimizing for mtry,splitrule and min.node.size, but I can not add the number of trees into the equation, as it gives me an error in the case of doing so. **
# define the parameter grid to search over
param_grid <- expand.grid(mtry = c(1:ncol(X)),
splitrule = c( "variance", "extratrees", "maxstat"),
min.node.size = c(1, 5, 10))

```
# set up the cross-validation scheme
cv_scheme <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                          number = 5,
                          verboseIter = TRUE)

# perform the grid search using caret
rf_model <- train(x = X,
                  y = y,
                  method = "ranger",
                  trControl = cv_scheme,
                  tuneGrid = param_grid)

# view the best parameter values
rf_model$bestTune
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do it, is to add a `num.trees` argument in `train` and iterate over that argument.

The other way is to create your customized model see this chapter [Using Your Own Model](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html)

there is an RPubs paper by Pham Dinh Khanh demonstrating that [here](https://rpubs.com/phamdinhkhanh/389752)

```r
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(ranger)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
x=PimaIndiansDiabetes[,-ncol(PimaIndiansDiabetes)]
y=PimaIndiansDiabetes[,ncol(PimaIndiansDiabetes)]

param_grid=expand.grid(mtry = c(1:4),
                       splitrule = c( "variance", "extratrees"),
                       min.node.size = c(1, 5))
cv_scheme <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                          number = 5,
                          verboseIter = FALSE)
models=list()
for (ntree in c(4,100)){
set.seed(123)
rf_model <- train(x = x,
                  y = y,
                  method = "ranger",
                  trControl = cv_scheme,
                  tuneGrid = param_grid,
                  num.trees=ntree)
name=paste0(ntree,"_tr_model")
models[[name]]=rf_model
}

models[["4_tr_model"]]
#> Random Forest 
#> 
#> 768 samples
#>   8 predictor
#>   2 classes: 'neg', 'pos' 
#> 
#> No pre-processing
#> Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
#> Summary of sample sizes: 614, 615, 614, 615, 614 
#> Resampling results across tuning parameters:
#> 
#>   mtry  splitrule   min.node.size  Accuracy   Kappa    
#>   1     variance    1                    NaN        NaN
#>   1     variance    5                    NaN        NaN
#>   1     extratrees  1              0.6808675  0.2662428
#>   1     extratrees  5              0.6783125  0.2618862
...

models[["100_tr_model"]]
#> Random Forest 
...
#> 
#>   mtry  splitrule   min.node.size  Accuracy   Kappa    
#>   1     variance    1                    NaN        NaN
#>   1     variance    5                    NaN        NaN
#>   1     extratrees  1              0.7473559  0.3881530
#>   1     extratrees  5              0.7564808  0.4112127
...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>